# Adding a POI with TraCI::POIScope

Tags: veins, sumo, point-of-interest

I get this error message when I try to add a POI to a vehicle through TraCI.

```
<!> Error: libsumo::TraCIException: ..  
Answered with error to command (199), [description: Could not add PoI.]

std::string imgFile = "img.png";
poiScope->add("POI1", mVehicleController->getPosition().x.value(), mVehicleController->getPosition().y.value(), standardColor, "png", 1, imgFile, 40, 40, 1);
```

I have checked the passed values and they are correct.

Disclaimer: This is an artery simulation, but since it's essentially a fork of veins I added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up if there already is another POI with the same id.

Comment: Oh, so IDs should be universally unique, not just unique to each vehicle? Thanks

Comment: Yes, a POI has nothing to do with a specific vehicle it is rather a net property.